# CyberArk vs Azure Key vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, cyber-ark

I was trying to understand on usages for CyberArk. Currently we are using Azure Key Vault for storing secret & credentials.
Do anyone have any details when should use CyberArk or what is advantages of CyberArk over Azure Key vault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CyberArk** :

- CyberArk is a tool, it used to maintain secret and store data by rotating all the important account credentials
- It is for security purpose which can **protect from hacking threats** efficiently and defend the **malware**
- It is per-company, license-based affordable platform,Quite expensive compare to key vault
- In cyberark **storage engine** it holds the data and ensure securing of data authenticated and controlled access

**Benefits of CyberArk**

- CyberArk can **Ease of tracking credential** with Privileged Account Security
- it continuously update privilege policies for users for **Lack of redundancy in updating policies** and less time consumption in password management
- CyberArk user must have safe ownership to get access to the specific safe and **Propagation of password changes across the applications**

**Azure Key Vault**

- In azure key vault it supported latest version of the secrets and it can refer key vault linked service to store the credential
- To store secrets and encrypt it is the valuable feature and ability to store easy and **straightforward** to use
- Pricing model is based on No of keys that you store and it's quite reasonable, to set secrets [key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault)

**Note:** *If the single user storing and single subscription means they can use key vault, if it is huge project among different organization, & single organization from different account need to manage means better to use CyberArk*

For your reference :

[▷ CyberArk Tutorial | What is CyberArk (mindmajix.com)](https://mindmajix.com/cyberark-tutorial)