# Hashicorp Vault vs Azure Key Vault

Tags: key, azure-keyvault, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to put together analysis/metrics around secret management tools available in cloud application development theatre. I have seen [CyberArk vs Azure Key vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457436/cyberark-vs-azure-key-vault) . Upon doing a general search I could not find comparison between Hashicorp's vault and Azure Key Vault product. Has anybody done this exercise before? If yes, can you please share your observations here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Azure KeyVault**

Azure Key Vault uses for key management it can easily generate and manage encryption keys for your data. This KV method is mainly for securing and safely managing access to API keys, tokens, and other secrets.

- Key Vault offers the simplicity of changing passwords numerous times and the ease of retrieving user account information from the cloud.
- **In certificate management**: quickly provision, manage and deploy both public and private TLS/SSL certificates for use with azure and your internal connected resources
- **In secrets management tool** Azure Key Vault is categorized as [Certificate Lifecycle Management (CLM)](https://www.g2.com/categories/certificate-lifecycle-management-clm)
- **Store secrets backed by hardware security modules**: secrets and keys can be protected either by software or FIPS 140-2 level validated HSMs
- In key vault you no need to worry about security and managing your own identities technical support is also beneficial.

Hope you know more about azure key vault

**Hasicorp vault**

It's a cloud agnostic secrets management system it allows you to safely store and manage sensitive data in hybrid cloud environments & used to generate that the value of vault ***moving away from static long-lived credentials to more dynamic short-lived credentials*** or encrypt application data on the fly. *Here I will explain you vault use cases*

****Secrets management****: Basically storing secrets centrally inside a vault and consuming those secrets and disturbing them

****Encrypting application data****: Keeping application data secure with centralized key management for the encryption keys inside the vault

****Identity-based Access****: Making a vault broker of identity so that you can Authenticate and access different clouds, system, and endpoints using trusted identities

- Hasicorp vault still be configured by a separate team other than developers use of convenient and stable
- In ***secrets management tool*** hashiCorp Vault is categorized as [Data Center Security](https://www.g2.com/categories/data-center-security), [Database Security](https://www.g2.com/categories/database-security), [Privileged Access Management (PAM)](https://www.g2.com/categories/privileged-access-management-pam), [Encryption](https://www.g2.com/categories/encryption), and [Password Manager](https://www.g2.com/categories/password-manager)
- On this model we were using, there was neither revocation nor deletion. Every financial year, a client interaction occurs, and you are charged for that client for the entire year. So, the pricing only includes minor adjustments like that.
- Here because of separate team technical support was unreliable difficult to get the technical assistance,
- HashiCorp Vault is now a supported ***third-party integration with Azure Key Vault Managed HSM*** used to automatically unsealing while keeping keys within a secure hardware boundary

For you Reference :

https://www.contino.io/insights/hashicorp-vault & [Hasicorp vault github](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault)

https://sensu.io/blog/what-is-hashicorp-vault-and-how-does-it-work